Can I update latest Gerrit commit without submitting the chained commits?
I have chained commits in Gerrit (all in review, not yet merged).
I want to update the most recent one without changing previous commits
I've tried updating latest patch (git ammend) and pushing it to Gerrit, it updated all chained commits as well (Including kicking pre-commit for al of them).
Cherry-pick only the relevant patch is not possible due to merge-conflicts.

What do you mean by "it updated all chained commits"? Did the hashes of these chained commits also get changed? Amending the last commit should only add a new patch set to its pending change. Its parent and ancestors should be unchanged.

Meaning there was no code change, just updated the patchset number and kicked all pre-commits. Not sure about the hashes.

This doesn't happen for me.  Mine warns me I'm uploading 2 or 3 commits, and in the process realizes only the last commit actually changed, and only affects that one.  If I look in Gerrit, none of the prior pending commits are affected. Please provide the exact commands you use.
